# Automapper v5 Ignore unmapped properties

Tags: automapper, automapper-5

Previously when I used Automapper v3.x ignoring unmapped properties could be done by simply adding a `.IgnoreUnmappedProperties()` extension which looked like this

```
public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{

public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreUnmappedProperties<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    var typeMap = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TSource, TDestination>();
    if (typeMap != null)
    {
        foreach (var unmappedPropertyName in typeMap.GetUnmappedPropertyNames())
        {
            expression.ForMember(unmappedPropertyName, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
    }

        return expression;
    }
}
```

How can this extension be rewritten to work with Version 5.x. I can of course add the following to each property.

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.LastUpdatedBy, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

or not call

```
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Comment: The solution for AutoMapper 11 is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72367321/automapper-map-a-few-and-ignore-the-rest/73333328#73333328

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that using the `CreateMap` method's `memberList` parameter to specify the validation that you want.

```
CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>(MemberList.None)
```

The `MemberList.None` should do the trick. You can also switch between the source or destination validations.

[Automapper - Selecting members to validate](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html)

Comment: This approach is actually pretty bad as you will end up with invalid mappings. By default, it's targeting the destination, so I would consider it multiple times before changing that behavior.