# Automapper "map a few and ignore the rest"

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I know there are a lot of questions (and answers) about this BUT **none** of these works for me when using .net6 and automapper 11.01.1
They seem to have removed many of these `Ignore`, `IgnoreAllUnmapped` and `ForAllOtherMembers` in the latest automapper.
If I use ignore with `ForAllMembers` (before or after `ForMember`) it will ignore all fields, even those I specify with a map.

The problem: I have two classes with fields with the same name, but I only want to map a few and ignore the rest. (please don't say "why do you need automapper" that's not the question here).

I need to use automapper in this case but not sure if they support this anymore? Am I missing a nuget maybe? I only use the "AutoMapper 11.01.1"

```
public class User1
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Foo";
    public int Age { get; set; } = 7;
    public string Phone { get; set;} = "123456789";
}
public class User2
{ 
    public string FirstLastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User1, User2>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstLastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            //.ForMember(dest => dest.Age, src => src.Ignore());  // works BUT I do not want to ignore every field manually
            //.ForAllMembers(dest => dest.Ignore())               // doesn't work, clears all fields
            //.ValidateMemberList(MemberList.None)                // doesn't work
            ;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var user1 = new User1();
    
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(mc => mc.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfile()));
    Mapper mapper = new Mapper(config);
    
    var user2 = mapper.Map<User2>(user1);
    user2.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore all destination members, except the ones that are mapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367591/how-to-ignore-all-destination-members-except-the-ones-that-are-mapped)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't think IgnoreAllUnmapped still exists in automapper, unless I'm missing some nuget or using the wrong nuget.

Comment: Possible solution is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71311303/replacement-for-automappers-forallothermembers/74394201#74394201

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AutoMapper: "Ignore the rest"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954480/automapper-ignore-the-rest)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We ran into the same issue. I created this extension method which should provide the functionality you're looking for.

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAllMembers<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expr)
{
    var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);

    foreach (var property in destinationType.GetProperties())
        expr.ForMember(property.Name, opt => opt.Ignore());

    return expr;
}
```

The usage for it:

```
CreateMap<ModelOne, ModelTwo>()
    .IgnoreAllMembers()
    .ForMember(x => x.DescriptionOne, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.DescriptionOne));
```

It works by looping through all the properties of the destination type and ignoring them. This means it needs to be called *before* you provide your member mappings. Calling it after will override your mappings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thats cool, thank you for the respond. I guess there are no ways of doing this with automapper any more, and that's sooooo strange.

Comment: @steb you're much more polite about it than I was when I found about this when trying to upgrade solely to get .NET 7 working. Especially annoyed considering my code had been working just fine for 3 years.

Comment: Yea same here, it wad not a piece of cake and update the nugets  but now it’s done and no need to look back 

Comment: Thanks. Mapping was working before and now I have to use above solution to ignore other properties mapping being done automatically for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I changed previous answer of Pullen. Great thanks to him.This is a method for ignore non existing in the destination properties.

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreNonExistingMembers<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expr)
{
    var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
    var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);

    foreach (var property in destinationType.GetProperties())
    {
        if (sourceType.GetProperty(property.Name) != null)
            continue;
        expr.ForMember(property.Name, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }

    return expr;
}
```

Comment: Is it better than IgnoreAllNonExisting from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954480/automapper-ignore-the-rest/6280647#6280647 ?